# disable prtscr+alt gr+e , accidentally killing session

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, session, kill

when i press the key combination:

```
altr gr + prtscr + e
```

my session gets killed, either x or a tty. i discovered this by  (repeated) accident... this was not an issue for me before. my current laptop (lenovo x230) has the prtscr key besides the right alt key rather than on the top right section of the keyboard, so i accidentally press them both sometimes.

[standard keyboard layout](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/KeyboardWithPrintScreenRinged.svg)

[lenovo x230,t430s keyboard layout](http://www.lenovo.com/images/OneWebImages/SubSeries/gallery/laptops/ThinkPad-X230-Laptop-PC-Overhead-Keyboard-View-gallery-845x475.jpg)

---

how do i disable it?

thanks!

Comment: I disagree with Klaus that you "do not want to disable it". It can be helpful for power users, but most users who have a hanging system will just hold the power button for five seconds. For public places like a library it makes sense to disable SysRq as it could be used to bypass restrictions or learn more about the system. If you often press it by accident, then it is very worthwhile to disable SysRq. Please post the edits to your question as answer since they actually form an answer :-)

Comment: thanks for the tips. i've removed the confusing edits, accepted the answer and posted the other part of my question in a new question, for clarity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/422866/map-sysrq-to-a-key-other-than-altrgrprtscr

Comment: @Lekensteyn You're definitely right on the public library and comparable places. SysRq may become a playground for the kids there: So much key combinations to try on a rainy day :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if so, how do i disable it?

You don't want to disable the **Magic SysRq**!

The key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRq</kbd> triggers the **Magic SystemRequest** and allows to enter combinations of single keys to shut down your system in a controlled way, even when everything else has become completely unresponsive.

This is your life-saver. Don't throw it over board ;)

---

**EDIT:** The behaviour of SysRq can be controlled by writing the bitmask for the allowed actions to the file `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`. A value of `0` disables everything, so

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

will do the job. But you have been warned ;)

---

**EDIT:** To disable permanently, add the line:

```
kernel.sysrq = 0
```

to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. either that or create a file in `/etc/sysctl.d/*` with the mentioned line.

Comment: i've never *had* to use the "magic sysrq", yet i've repeatedly shutdown my session because of this. i want to change it to a harder-to-hit combination, or disable it if it cannot be modified without recompiling the kernel

Comment: @rrosa Since you insist on it, I've updated the answer ;)

Comment: thank klaus. i had to do this `sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=0` since `sudo echo` was giving me permission denied.
anyway, i'd still like to know how modify the shortcut rather than having to disable everything.
thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it is such a big problem to disable the magic keys? If someone has a stable system it is not so important to have them enabled, IMHO. There are even some distribution which disable them by default, like Arch.

Comment: i've never had to use them myself, but i guess it would be useful to flush to disk before rebooting when something goes really wrong. also useful on a system to which i do not have access and can't reboot it manually (server)

Comment: found sysrq doc with all possible values: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt