# REISUB not working when Ubuntu freezes

Tags: 12.04, reboot, sysrq

I am using 12.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 15 3521. Whenever the system hangs up with keyboard becoming unresponsive, REISUB does not give any results. Now I edited etc/sysctl.conf file as was suggested in an answer to a similar question with no positive change whatsoever. Also my laptop only has a prntscr key with no specific sysrq key designated as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

I never had a keyboard with a separate <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key at home. Typically, the system requests are triggered when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PrtScr</kbd> plus the respective REISUB keys.

Comment: I tried Alt+Prntscr+Respective keys but there is no positive result

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422459/disable-prtscralt-gre-accidentally-killing-session/422463#422463) for further directions.

Comment: The value in the file you mentioned is set to 1.